# MS Office Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, shortcuts, microsoft-word-2013

I just downloaded MS Word 2013. Firstly I cant find it easily on my PC. How can I make a shortcut called WORD 2013 on my desktop like the 'old' computers we used when we were younger. Secondly, after I manage to find word and type up a document I cannot save it as a word 2013 document. The Save As option gives me a  drop-down list that includes options like "Word Document (*.docx) and Word 97 - 2003 Document (*.docx) but NOT Word 2013 Document. Why not?

thanks.

Comment: "Word Document (.docx)" is compatible with all versions of word newer than 2003.

Comment: [Desktop shortcut for Excel, Outlook, Word 2013 on the Windows 8.1 / 10 Desktop?](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=203)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows 8/8.1/10, You can search in start, i.e. type 'word' after pressing windows button on PC or opening it from bottom left corner and as soon as you see search result it will say **Word 2013 Desktop Application** you can pin them in start and taskbar. To create shortcut on desktop however, launch the application i.e. Word 2013 then open Task Manager by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ESC, under process tab look for Word 2013 right click on it and click on open file location and it will open the installation directory with WINWORD.EXE selected just right click on WINWORD.EXE and select Send To > Desktop (Create Shortcut). You can repeat the process for other Office Softwares like Excel And PowerPoint

And don't worry about extension just save your files instead doing 'Save As', at first save it will ask where to save, and default directory will be My Documents. DOCX extension can be opened by every Office Package after 2003, i.e. 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016. And if you want to make that file readable in Legacy versions (before 2007) save them as DOC.

Comment: Thanks, the first tip worked and it's now on my desktop. When I try and save it though, it still doesn't save as a word 2013 document, and even when I save on the default (Word Document (*.docx)) it doesn't save as the word 2013 document; instead it saves as an apache Office (or something like that / notepad ) document.

Comment: Try reinstalling, maybe something went wrong while installing and it wasn't installed properly. Because I don't see why is that happening, has to be a bad settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, just "Saving As" should save your new document as a FileName.docx automatically.  Opening any word document created in an earlier version should not be any problem in Word 2013.